# Signed URL for subdomain in Laravel 8

Tags: php, url, routes, subdomain, laravel-8

I'm trying to generate URLs signed in Laravel 8 so that the application's clients can cancel the event without needing access. I'm using multi-tenant with two subdomains foo.domain.com and bar.domain.com. However, Laravel generates signed URLs only for the main domain. Is there any way to change Laravel's behavior to understand and generate a signed URL for the subdomains?

```
public function generateLink($id, $username, $whatsapp)
{
    return Url::temporarySignedRoute('confirmpage', now()->addMinutes(20), [
        'id' => $id,
        'user' => $username,
        'whatsapp' => $whatsapp
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should config dynamic domain in routes:

```
    $domain = '{external}';
    
    Route::domain($domain)->group(function () {
        Route::name('external.')->group(function () {
            Route::name('verification.')->group(function () {
                Route::post('verification/verify/{id}/{hash}', [\App\Controllers\VerificationController::class, 'verify'])->name('verify');
            });
        });
    });
```

Then override it:

```
    $verifyUrl = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
        'external.verification.verify',
        Carbon::now()->addMinutes(config('access.verification.expires', 1440)),
        [
            'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
            'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
            'external' => parse_url(env('MYAPP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST),
        ]
    );
```